# how to send email alert with detail error message if azure databricks notebook fails

Tags: azure-databricks

I have schedule notebook at morning 6 am. I have set the email alert from scheduling option but its not showing the detail error message. its simply written as "job failed".

How to set the email alert which includes the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately, email alert doesn't provides the details error message in the email.

You need to click on the link provided in the email to get more details on the error message.

[image]

The link take you the associated job which contains the detailed error message.

[image]